# r - ggplot2 - secondary duplicate axis log transform is incorrect

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot 2.2.0 to create a secondary duplicated axis using the log transform.

```
# install.packages("install.load") # install to use the load_package function
install.load::load_package("ggplot2", "data.table")

sand <- structure(list(`Sieve #` = c("3/8”", "4", "8", "16", "30", "50", 
"Pan"), `Size (mm)` = c(9.525, 4.75, 2.36, 1.18, 0.6, 0.3, NA
), `Mass Sieve (kg)` = c(0.642, 0.508, 0.474, 0.408, 0.38, 0.348, 
0.376), `Mass Retained + Sieve (kg)` = c(0.642, 0.524, 0.58, 
0.526, 0.598, 0.899, 0.463), `Mass Retained (kg)` = c(0, 0.016, 
0.106, 0.118, 0.218, 0.551, NA), `Cumulative Mass Retained (kg)` = c(0, 
0.016, 0.122, 0.24, 0.458, 1.009, NA), `Cumulative % Retained` = c(0, 
1, 11, 22, 42, 92, NA), `% Passing` = c(100, 99, 89, 78, 58, 
8, NA)), .Names = c("Sieve #", "Size (mm)", "Mass Sieve (kg)", 
"Mass Retained + Sieve (kg)", "Mass Retained (kg)", "Cumulative Mass Retained (kg)", 
"Cumulative % Retained", "% Passing"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))


x1 <- c(0.075, 0.15, 0.3, 0.6, 1.18, 2.36, 4.75, 9.5, 12.5, 19, 25, 37.5, 50)

x1_label <- c("0.075", "0.150", "0.300", "0.600", "1.180", "2.36", "4.75", "9.5", 
    "12.5", "19.0", "25.0", "37.5", "50.0")

x2 <- c("No. 200", "No. 100", "No. 50", "No. 30", "No. 16", "No. 8", "No. 4", 
    "3/8 in.", "1/2 in.", "3/4 in.", "1 in.", "1 1/2 in.", "2 in.")


ggplot(sand, aes(`Size (mm)`, `% Passing`)) + geom_point() + 
    geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(name = "Sieve size (mm)",
limits = c(0.075, 
    50), expand = c(0.001, 0), breaks = x1, labels = x1_label, minor_breaks = NULL, 
    trans = "log", position = "bottom", sec.axis = dup_axis(name = "Sieve size", 
        breaks = x1, labels = x2)) +
labs(title = "Group 1 Sand Gradation Results (ASTM C136)") + scale_y_continuous(limits =
c(0, 
    100), expand = c(0.01, 0), breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10), minor_breaks = seq(0, 
    100, by = 5), name = "% Passing") +
theme_bw() + theme(plot.margin = margin(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, "pt"),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.1))
```

The bottom x-axis and the top x-axis do not match in the image shown below.

Is it possible to have a duplicated secondary axis using the log transform?

If so, then how should the existing code be modified to get the desired result?

If not, then do you have any suggestions.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: got using your code:       Error in scale_x_continuous(name = "Sieve size (mm)", limits = c(0.075,  : 
  unused arguments (position = "bottom", sec.axis = dup_axis(name = "Sieve size", breaks = x1, labels = x2))

Comment: @AndreiR  I just copied and pasted the R code, except for installing `install.load` in R and the figure was created. Can you try it again? Thank you.

Comment: sorry, no luck. Indeed my ggplot version was not correct. Updated it but keep having the same error.

Comment: @AndreiR  I'm sorry, but I just commented out the first line of the code which may help. I tested the code on RStudio on MS Windows and R on GNU/Linux without the first line of code and I haven't had any errors producing the plot. Thank you for trying again.

Comment: yes. Now got it. It seems a bug to me. Taking out limits from x or changing its lower value modifies the pattern. Also if use 'sqrt' as scale_x_continuous trans the difference is there.